# Power BI Dynamic Odata unable to edit parameters after creation

Tags: odata, powerbi-datasource, s4hana, dynamicparameters, reportparameter

I am fetching data from SAP S/4HANA CDS Views into Power BI through Odataservice. The Odataservice URL had the parameter values hardcoded, which is why my report showed data only for that particular value.

To be more specific, company code is the parameter which is getting data only for one value say 1000. I made this dynamic by editing the datasource M Query.

Now the report is able to override the data coming from SAP OData service.

However, it is only displaying the default value I set while parameter creation. I am unable to edit it even after publishing, as the fields are greyed out in PowerBI Service settings. So now the report only shows the default company code value I set in the parameter creation step.

The parameter values I entered:

[image]

The parameter values in the report display:

[image]

Any advice is much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Dynamic M Query parameters are only supported for DirectQuery data sources. You will either need a Dataset per company code, or load all the company codes and then filter.

Comment: @Sam Nseir:Thank you for the response.